# Why the next input is next to the last output

Tags: python

I want to understand why the next input is next to the last output in this code.

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    N = input()
    N = list(N)
    for j in reversed(N):
        print(j,end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set the `end` to an empty space (`" "`). If you want to input it on the next line (and the reversed of the input on the next line as well), put `print()` after the for loop like so:

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    N = input()
    N = list(N)
    for j in reversed(N):
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Ok, but the end=" " is in the nested loop not the outer one, I think the outer loop should be natural I mean it will end every time with a new line.

Comment: The last print statement used will be the one with `end=" "` for each iteration, so it makes sense that it would get the input from the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Let me describe your code as it is.

```
T = int(input())
```

I will assume here that you will insert a valid number which doesn't contain `spaces` ,`alphabet` or `Unicode`.

so let's say you've inserted number `3` which is actually string and you already converted it to `int`.

So your loop will be equal to `for i in range(0, T)` where `T` is your `int`.

Which means your loop will play 3 times.

Now moving to the second part of your code under the loop:

```
for i in range(T):
    N = input()
```

You are taking input while you are using the same variable to overwrite. Now anything will be inserted will be converted to a `list` later.

Let's say you inserted `123`

So it's will became [`1`, '2', '3'] according to `N = list(N)`

Now you are looping again over it using reverse order:

```
for j in reversed(N):
```

So the loop will reverse `[`1`, '2', '3']` to `[`3`, '2', '1']`

Now you are using `end=" "` which will output in same line where each line end in the loop will just end with `blank space` and then it's will take the next line side to side

so it's going to be
`3 2 1`

And the scenario will repeat itself again till the loop finish.

Kindly take a look on [Rules for Python variables](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_variable_names.asp)

Also you don't need to use the same variable name over and over unless you need! that's will make your code more easier and readable !